# Term for timespan between generations

Tags: genetics, terminology

Is there a terminology for the average timespan between generations, like ΔG ?
I mean by that the time from the parental generation being mature to the filial generation being mature.

Comment: Note that $\Delta G$ sounds more like a time difference in generation unit like $\Delta G = G_1 - G_0$, where for example, $G_1$ could be the generation at which the state of your model has reached a basin of attraction (or whatever) and $G_0$ could be the initial generation. $Delta t$ would sound a little bit like an actual time (in years or whatever) between two generations (although often the unit of $t$ are defined to the generation time). +1 anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean generation time?

There are [several definitions in use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_time), but one is "the average difference in age between parent and offspring" (or "age at which members of a given cohort are expected to reproduce") which would be the same as the time period you're asking about.

(The difference between these two depends whether the population is at equilibrium or not.)

The two above are 'shortest generation time'; a third definition (which is the first in the link) is a little more complex but is more useful where individuals reproduce over a prolonged period.